# How much weight can I hang on my cabinet doors?

Tags: cabinets, hinges

I want to mount shelves on the inside of the doors of my Ikea kitchen cabenets, to make better use of the space - as it is, the cabinets are too deep to see everything on the very deep shelves. However, I'm worried about damaging the hinges if I hang too much weight on the door.

This is the sort of thing I want to install:

[image: shelves on cabinet doors]

The cabinet is tall, 70-ish inches, and the door is attached with three hinges that look like this:

[image: my hinges]

[This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/mQLRvYk1rCw?t=107) shows a similar product being installed on cabinet doors with hinges that look a lot like mine, which gives me hope.

Comment: Do you know the product name of the cabinets? Or the name on the hinges? How many hinges per door?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a typical loading chart based on height of door and number of hinges. See page 3 near the bottom.

http://downloads.cabinetparts.com/auto/SaliceGeneral.pdf

Notice there are heavy duty hinges too.

If the shelving is only 3” wide (deep) rather than 10” or so...that’s a clue too.

Answer (score 1):

This is opinion only, with the 3 hinges on each panel you have now, I am sure the are rated for the doors you have now. The shelves you have pictured has the capacity to wear those original hinges out prematurely. Yes, they will work for a while, but they will fail over time. They will not let the door fall off, just not close properly anymore.

Many hinges of the European style you have are easily swapped out. Look up the hinges that will hold the extra weight, set those in place, then add your shelves.